# Stopping Access to Spring Backend Service via CORS, but React Frontend Can No Longer Access Backend

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, cors

We have an application with two containers deployed within the same pod hosted on AWS EKS. The React UI container is running on port 8080 while the Spring Boot backend is running on 8081.

The CORS configuration on Spring Boot (3.1.2):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class WebMvcConfigurerConfig {
    @Value("${PUBLIC_URL}")
    private String url;
    
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                log.info("url: " + url);
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(url, "svc.local.cluster", "http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081", " http://127.0.0.1:8080");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

PUBLIC_URL is an environment variable that defines the url that the application is hosted on. For example: https://acme.com/myapp

This configuration successfully stops the backend being able to be accessed via curl or other tools. However, the UI can no longer contact the backend.

What would be the proper allowedOrigins?

Comment: If the backend can be accessed by the UI, it must also be accessible by curl, because curl can be used to make the same requests (including `Origin` header) that the UI also makes. In other words: CORS is not used to protect the backend, but to protect the _client_ against making unwanted requests.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen What is the point of allowedOrigins?

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS